# Broadcast receiver not registered with AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have problems to register a BroadcastReceiver.

It works when I register it with registerReceiver :

```
registerReceiver(new NotifReceiver(), new IntentFilter(NotifReceiver.POST_NOTIF));
```

But not with AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.NotifReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".receiver.NotifReceiver.POST_NOTIF" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

NotifReceiver.java :

```
public class NotifReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String POST_NOTIF = "POST_NOTIF";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(POST_NOTIF)) {
            Log.d("debug", "action received");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did an answer solved your problem ? If yes you should mark it as a solution. Then if people have the same problem they quickly can see what is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing below two lines in your Manifest.xml:

```
1. android:name=".receiver.NotifReceiver"
2. <action android:name=".receiver.NotifReceiver.POST_NOTIF"/>
```

to

```
1. android:name="*full.pkg.name*.receiver.NotifReceiver"
2. <action android:name="*full.pkg.name*.receiver.NotifReceiver.POST_NOTIF"/>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Main thing here to note is - in order to make Receivers visible/active from outside an application's boundary it is mandatory to define its name with full package qualifier. All the best for the rest of your project!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Google Guidelines about the action tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html).

> It's best to use the package name as a prefix to ensure uniqueness.

Then your should declare your action as:

```
public static final String POST_NOTIF = "com.my.package.POST_NOTIF";
```

And reference in your Manifest as:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.my.package.POST_NOTIF" />
</intent-filter>
```

Note that `android:name` just need to match the value of the `POST_NOTIF` static string.

But in order to avoid conflict with other app, you should put an unique value for the string you use as an action. That's why Google recommend to prefix it with your package.

Comment: That wasn't the problem but I changed the action to follow the Google guidelines.

Comment: Ok fine, no problem. Good luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

replace  `<action android:name=".receiver.NotifReceiver.POST_NOTIF" />`
with this  `<action android:name="POST_NOTIF" />`